# can't set text to Jbutton on a grid for a game

Tags: java, arrays, swing

i am creating a game based on a grid and a parser from english to java. i am having trouble making the command draw on a grid. right now im trying to simply write a letter onto the grid so i can see it and then later i will add graphics. basically, the game accepts commands in english, then parses them to java and should draw it to a grid. i have done most of the code, but its not working. im not too good with swing and GUI in java. below is the code for the parser which has been reduced, and the grid its self. i have some methods that should draw but they dont, im not sure why.

ServerPlayerParsing class:

```
public class ServerPlayerParsing {    
ServerGridGenerator serverGrid = new ServerGridGenerator (10, 10);
public String validate(String command){
serverGrid.frameGen();
if (wordCount(command)== 3) { 
        String[] commandArray = command.split(" ");
        commandParsing(commandArray);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Format incorrect!");
        System.out.println("Correct format = [COMMAND 1] [COMMAND 2] [COMMAND 3]");
    }
 return "";
}
public  int wordCount(String command){
String[] commandCount = command.split("\\s");
return commandCount.length;
}
public  String commandParsing(String[] commandArray) {
switch (commandArray[0]) {
    case "move":
    secondCommand (commandArray);
    break;
    default: System.out.println("Error in first command!");
}       
return " ";
}
public String secondCommand (String commandArray[]) {
switch (commandArray[1]) {
    case "forward":
    forwardMovement(commandArray);
    break;
    case "backward":
    backwardMovement (commandArray);
    break;
    case "left":
    leftMovement (commandArray);
    break;
    case "right":
    rightMovement (commandArray);
    break;
    default: System.out.println("Error in second command!");
} 
return " ";
}
public   String forwardMovement (String commandArray[]) {
switch (commandArray[2]) {
         case "1":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveForward(1);
         break;
         case "2":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveForward(2);
         break;
         default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
        }
return " ";
    }
    public   String backwardMovement (String commandArray[]) {
 switch (commandArray[2]) {
         case "1":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveBackward(1);
         break;
         case "2":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveBackward(2);
         break;
         default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
        }
        return " ";
}
    public   String leftMovement (String commandArray[]) {
    switch (commandArray[2]) {
         case "1":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveLeft(1);
         break;
         case "2":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveLeft(2);
         break;
         default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
        }
        return " ";
}
    public   String rightMovement (String commandArray[]) {
 switch (commandArray[2]) {
         case "1":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveRight(1);
         break;
         case "2":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveRight(2);
         break;
         default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
        }
 return " ";
}

}
```

ServerGridGenerator:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class ServerGridGenerator extends JFrame {
public int serverPlayerXPos = 0;
public int serverPlayerYPos = 0;
int row;
int column;
public  void frameGen(){
row = 10;
column = 10;
int sizeGrid = 700;
ServerGridGenerator frame = new ServerGridGenerator(row, column);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeGrid, sizeGrid));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public ServerGridGenerator(int row, int column) {
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];
Container pane = getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, column));
for(int y=0; y<column; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<row; x++) {
        squareButtons[y][x] = new JButton("");
        squareButtons[y][x].setOpaque(true);
        squareButtons[y][x].setBackground(Color.white);
        squareButtons[y][x].setEnabled(false);
        pane.add(squareButtons[y][x]);
    }        
}
}


public void serverPlayerMoveRight (int moveBy){
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];
for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
  serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos + 1;
  squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
}
}
 public void serverPlayerMoveLeft (int moveBy){
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];
for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
  serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos - 1;
  squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
}
}
public void serverPlayerMoveForward (int moveBy){
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];
for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
  serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos + 1;
  squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
}
}
public void serverPlayerMoveBackward (int moveBy){
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];
for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
  serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos - 1;
  squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
}
}
}
```

logically im pretty sure this works, but im not too familiar with java and if im allowed to modify text on the JButton after the program is running, either way could you please help me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your frame and your code for the grid are seperate, it shouldnt be like that. create one method for the grid, and other for the left, right, forward and backward movements. therefore your constructor will be called and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Your update event just has to call the setText method on whatever button you want the text on.

```
public void updateWhatever(String str, int buttonX, int buttonY){

squareButton[buttonX][buttonY].setText(str);

}
```

As for your code. You also probably need to fix your JButton 2D Array.

```
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [width][height];
```

That array should probably be a global variable instead of a local. The Data is dumped every time your method finishes and none of the data is saved anywhere in memory. Also, when constructing an array of objects you need to you need to instantiate each object in the array to access any of the methods.

```
int height = 9;
int width = 9;

for(int i = 0; i <height; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        squareButtons[i][j] = new JButton();

// Grid size 10x10
```

Try that out let me know how it goes.

**Update**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class ServerGridGenerator extends JFrame {
public int serverPlayerXPos = 0;
public int serverPlayerYPos = 0;
int row = 10;
int column = 10;
int sizeGrid = 700;
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];

public  void frameGen(){

ServerGridGenerator frame = new ServerGridGenerator(row, column);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeGrid, sizeGrid));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public ServerGridGenerator(int r, int c) {
squareButtons = new JButton [r][c];
Container pane = getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(r, c));
for(int y=0; y<c; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<r; x++) {
         squareButtons[y][x] = new JButton("");
         squareButtons[y][x].setOpaque(true);
         squareButtons[y][x].setBackground(Color.white);
         squareButtons[y][x].setEnabled(false);
         pane.add(squareButtons[y][x]);
     }        
}
}


 public void serverPlayerMoveRight (int moveBy){
 for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
     serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos + 1;
     squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
  }
 }

 public void serverPlayerMoveLeft (int moveBy){
 for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
    serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos - 1;
    squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
 }
 }
 public void serverPlayerMoveForward (int moveBy){
 for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
     serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos + 1;
     squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
  }
  }
 public void serverPlayerMoveBackward (int moveBy){
 for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
     serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos - 1;
     squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
  }
  }
  }
```

Here's what that class should look like. I have a similar project where I made the battle ship board game.

Comment: Thanks but thats not really what im looking for, but i believe ive solved the issue now. thanks